# Implementation of Quick Sort C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I've learned about Quick Sort is a sorting algorithm which follows the principle of Divide and Conquer with average time complexity as n(log n) and worst time complexity as n^2.

Here I've selected middle element as pivot.

When it exceeds length of array then function returns the array.

I have used four functions to implement Merge Sort:

Quick Sort Functions

- isSorted( ) returns true if array is sorted.
- pivotPositioning( ) arrange pivot at it's ideal position.
- quickSort( ) //wrapper function
- quickSort( ) returns sorted array

Initial Pivot is selected as the middle element of the array by default argument.

It's giving an error, showing last element as -2 for even length of array (i.e. 4,8,10) after the sorting is done. I would like to know what's causing the error?

```
//C++ Code
#include<iostream>

void print(int *, int);

bool isSorted(int *arr, int high, int low=0)
{
    for(int i=low; (i+1)<high; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void pivotPositioning(int *arr, int high, int low)
{
    for(int i=low; (i+1)<high; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

void quickSort(int *arr, int length, int pivot) 
{
    pivotPositioning(arr, pivot+1, 0);
    //print(arr, length);
    pivotPositioning(arr, length, pivot);
    //print(arr, length);
}

int *quickSort(int *arr, int length)
{
    int pivot = length/2;

    quickSort(arr, length, pivot);

    if (isSorted(arr, length) == false)
    {
        while (pivot > 0)
        {
            pivot--;
            quickSort(arr, length, pivot);
        }   

        while (pivot<length)
        {
            pivot++;
            quickSort(arr, length, pivot);
        }
        
    }

    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int length ;
    std::cout<<"Enter length of the array: ";
    std::cin>>length;

    int arr[length] ;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Enter Element "<<(i+1)<<" : ";
        std::cin>>arr[i];
    }

    quickSort(arr, length);

    print(arr, length);

    return 0;
}

void print(int *arr, int length)
{
    std::cout<<"Sorted Array: ";
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: It's an odd implementation of quick sort but i think the main problem is that `pivotPositioning` isn't actually partitioning around the pivot it just swaps adjacent pairs like a single iteration of bubble sort

Comment: How is your implementation divide-and-conquer? Your main `quickSort` has two loops. In qicksort, you pick a pivot p, then partition the array into [a[i] ≤ p; p; a[i] > p]. Now the pivot is in its correct poistion and you can sort the left and right subarrays. You algorithm doesn't do that at all.